# HTML.link from a frame to another opens in new window?How can i fix it?

Tags: html, frameset

i want to have a link in frame a and open in frame b without opening new window.

heres my code:

```
<html>
<base target="main.htm">
<body>
  <body link="blue" vlink="rgb(255,200,0)" alink="green" style="background-color:rgb(255,30,15)">
    <h2><b>ΠΕΡΙΕΧΟΜΕΝΑ</b></h2>
    <a href="personal.htm" target="main" border="0">ΠΡΟΣΩΠΙΚΑ ΣΤΟΙΧΕΙΑ </a><br/>
  <body/>
<html/>
```

Comment: To make the code show up properly, indent it by 4 spaces or highlight the text and hit Ctrl+K or use the code sample button. (The 101010 button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest a valid doctype declaration, unless of course you're going for HTML5.

Secondly, I would suggest your enclose your `<base>` tag inside `<head></head>` tag

Thirdly, if you're using either XHTML or HTML 5 (as it seems you're currently doing), you will need to close your `<base>` tag with `</base>`

As for answering your actual question, you'll need to use the target attribute, as follows:

```
<base target="main.htm" target="_parent">
```

Please note that, as far as I know you can't have a link from Frame A open in Frame B, unless it's a parent frame - if you understand what I mean. To get a full understanding of what the target attribute does, check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp) link.